# jQuery .load() - corner plugin not working in IE - Firefox is ok

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, internet-explorer-8, jquery-load

I have two simple pages I'm using for testing.

On my first page, I use `$.load()` to load a `div` from the second page.

Both pages contains the plugin to do the cornering. If I load the first page which loads the div from the second page, the cornering does not work. However, if I load the second page myself, the cornering does work so it's to do with $.load().

Here's some code, from page 1:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#load").load('testLoadCornering2.aspx #loadMe');   
            });
        </script>

        <script src="resources/js/curvycorners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="resources/js/curvycorners.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="load" class="BWTable">
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You see the page trying to load the second div.

And the second page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/curvycorners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/curvycorners.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="loadMe" class="BWTable">
        <p>
            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        </p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS it uses for the rounding (along with the rounded corners plugin):

```
 background-image: url(         '../../images/wp_form2.gif' );
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners plugin */
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners plugin */
```

In Firefox, this works fine - but in IE (specially version 8 I've been trying) the corners are never rounded.

To reiterate, manually going to the second page in IE 8 corners correctly, it's only when the .load() method is used.

Any help appreciated.

Note: I'm aware I shouldn't need to add the style sheets on both pages etc as they should be loaded from the first page, but I've added them to show you the full code of what it's trying to do.
Thanks,
Ricky

Comment: box model can be use instead  of border so may be it's work look like border-radius as same as in firefox and chrome.

Comment: This has now been solved and I've posted my answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lazarus. You put me on the right tracks and I've worked out the solution, this works. I feel a bit silly now!

Thanks again.

Page 1:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="resources/css/confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#load").load('testLoadCornering2.aspx #loadMe');  

            $.getScript('resources/js/curvycorners.js', function() {
                $(this).init();
            });
            $.getScript('resources/js/curvycorners.src.js', function() {
                $(this).init();
            });        
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="load" class="BWTable">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="loadMe" class="BWTable">
        <p>
            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        </p>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No need to feel silly, we've all been there. It's so easy to be too close to the problem to see the solution, "Can't see the Wood for the trees" is the best phrase to describe it. After a while you expect that 2 hours of scouring your code, picking it apart and even trying to run it on paper looking for a bug will end with a colleague leaning over your shoulder, glancing at the screen and immediately pointing to **the** most obvious bug you could imagine. :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, even though it's your own, it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that curvycorners will only spring into life for IE as Firefox fully supports the CSS3 rounded corners so while it's working in Firefox, that's only because curvycorners isn't attempting to do anything.

Your JQuery load is placed within a document-ready block and so won't execute until the whole page has loaded, including (I believe) the javascript, so curvycorners is running before your second page div is loaded. You need to find a way to either load the curvycorners script after your second page div or find out how to call curvycorners to reparse the page once it has loaded the second page div.

From the curvycorners documentation:

> If you need to change some attributes
>   or styling of the redrawable elements,
>   this should not be done directly
>   through the DOM. Instead, having
>   identified the DOM object (e.g. with
>   document.getElementById()), call
>
> `curvyCorners.adjust(DOMObj,
>   propertyName, newValue);`
>
> where:
>
> DOMObj is the element object with
>   className curvyRedraw that needs to be
>   changed;
>   propertyName is the name of
>   the property without a leading dot; if
>   it is a style property, it should be
>   expressed as 'style.property'.
>   newValue is the new value, e.g.
>   'none'.
>
> curvyCorners.adjust() must
>   take all three parameters described
>   above. It returns no useful value.

Comment: Thanks Lazarus. This put me on the right tracks. I've posted the answer for what worked for me.